# Rosinstall issue in 3d_navigation

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to run 3d_navigation, (which the ros_wiki says is 'unreleased and contains experimental code').

1. When I am trying to rosinstall, it is giving me following errors.

-ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: expected '', but found ''
in "", line 6, column 19. Can anybody tell what might be  missing ?

[The tutorial says](http://www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation) 'Use the following rosinstall to overlay your diamondback installation with the development versions of additional stacks and the 3d_navigation code

```
- svn:
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/sandbox/3d_navigation/
    local-name: stacks/3d_navigation
- svn:
    uri: https://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/octomap_mapping-experimental/
    local-name: stacks/octomap_mapping
- svn:
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/branches/arm_navigation_metrics
    local-name: stacks/motion_planning_common
```

How to use this in a rosinstall command?  example please.....

-I tried to use it like:

$ rosinstall /opt/ros/diamonback https:/code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/sandbox/3d_navigation/

(as the tutrial says:
Usage: rosinstall PATH [URI] [options])

-my opt/ros/diamondback/.rosinstall file looks OK too. Here is its content

```
- other:
    local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/ros
- other:
    local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
```

Can anybody help me understand what is going wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10415/rosinstall-issue-in-3d_navigation/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read the [rosinstall documentation.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall)

The usage of rosinstall would be as follows:

```
$ rosinstall MY_DEVELOPMENT_LOCATION /opt/ros/diamondback PATH_TO_ROSINSTALL_FILE
```

Assuming:
MY_DEVELOPMENT_LOCATION is where you want to work (usually ~/ros) . And PATH_TO_ROSINSTALL_FILE is where you saved the given rosinstall snippet into a file.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2